# What is the solution of limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x} $?

Tags: limits

What is the solution of this limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x} $$ I'm sure it's pretty basic but somehow I can't figure out how to solve it? Is it just $1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}n/n$?

Comment: Either way, the answer is 1 since the expression is just a constant

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x} $ sorry for misspelling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can just divide
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1.$$
The limit of a constant is always the constant itself:
$$\lim_{x\to p}\mathrm{const.}=\mathrm{const.}$$

Comment: I think OP means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac nn$, in which case it isn't as simple.

Comment: Uhm, it's still just as simple since it's a constant regardless

Comment: Actually @DonThousand is right - I ment $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x} $, Sorry for misspelling :/

Comment: +1 for self promotion

Comment: @vitamind That's not a thing. You get +10 per upvote, except if you reached 200 rep in a day.

Comment: @QC_QAOA I'm aware, but the idea behind $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac nn=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1$ is non-trivial at this level.

Comment: @DonThousand: I don't get it. Why should that be non-trivial at any level. If function $f$ is constant and equals $k$ then $|f(x) - k|=0$ which is always less than $\epsilon $ regardless of anything else. The fact that the variable tends to $a$ or to $\infty$ or the variable is integer or real does not play any role in this specific trivial case of limit of constant functions.

Comment: Upvote for you, upvote for him, everybody gets an upvote